# Changing bytes in existing binary file

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim OFD As New OpenFileDialog
    Try
        OFD.Filter = "Binary files (*.bin)|*.bin"
        If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            fullFile = File.ReadAllBytes(OFD.FileName)

            Dim writer As New BinaryWriter(OFD.OpenFile)
            writer.Seek(&H5B0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
            writer.Write(CUShort(&HB1AA))
            writer.Close()
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error")
    End Try
```

It should open file and then change bytes into it. But while open file I got message box with:

> Error Can't write in stream

And file is still not changed. Fix my code.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the OpenFileDialog.OpenFile() helper method:

> Opens the file selected by the user, with **read-only permission**.

Relevant phrase bolded, that means you cannot write to the file.  You need to use FileStream instead.  Like this:

```
    If OFD.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Using fs As New FileStream(OFD.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None)
            Using writer As New BinaryWriter(fs)
                writer.Seek(&H5B0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                writer.Write(CUShort(&HB1AA))
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```